# How to fix blue color of HTML select tags in iOS 15 using CSS

Tags: html, css, select, ios15

iOS 15 changed HTML select elements to default blue color.

How do you fix this with CSS?

Answer (score 7):

You need to explicitly set the color within your css or else it defaults to blue on iOS 15.